# How do i install ubuntu on an already created partition

Tags: installation, partitioning, macosx

I Have burn't Ubuntu 13.04 to a DVD and have it running on my Apple MacBook. Now I Want to install Ubuntu without harming OSX. I Have Created a partition on OSX which i would like to install Ubuntu On. Is it possible to install Ubuntu on that partition that was made by OSX and if so How?

Thanks For All The Help

Jai

Answer (score 0):

In the installer, when you get to the point of choosing your install location choose "other" this will give you a detailed menu allowing you to choose the partition you want to use.